# Is there a fundamental type for natural numbers in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, variables, int, variable-declaration

I have a problem in which I need to declare some variables as natural numbers. Which is the propper fundamental type that I should use for variables that should be natural numbers ? Like for integers is int ...

Comment: How about an `unsigned int`?  All natural numbers up to 2.147 billion...

Comment: @LukePark that's the range (on both negative and positive values) for 32-bit signed `int`. `unsigned` doubles the upper limit while the lower bound is `0`.

Comment: Ahh yeah.  Double that last value sorry.

Comment: What is the problem you are actually tackling? Mentioning it in your question (so **you should edit your question**) would help getting more relevant answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that a computer (and perhaps even the entire universe) is a finite machine; it has a finite (but very large number) of bits (my laptop has probably less than 10<sup>15</sup> bits).

Of course `int` are not the mathematical integers. On my machine `int` is a 32 bits signed integer (and `long` is a 64 bits signed integer), so `int`-s have only 2<sup>32</sup> possible values (and that is much less than the infinite cardinal of mathematical integers).

So a computer can only represent a finite set of numbers, but quite a large one. That is smaller than the infinite set of natural numbers (remember, some of them are not representable on the entire Earth; read about [Richard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard's_paradox)).

You might want to use `unsigned` (same as `unsigned int`, on my machine represents natural numbers up to 2<sup>32</sup>-1), `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long` or (from `<stdint.h>`) types like `uint32_t`, `uint64_t` ... you would get unsigned binary numbers of 32 or 64 bits. Some compilers and implementations might know about `uint128_t` or something similar.

If that is not enough, consider using [big ints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). You could use a library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) (but even a big computer is not able to represent extremely large natural numbers -with all their bits-..., and your own brain cannot comprehend them neither).

Answer (score 7):

The following types resemble natural numbers set with 0 included in C++:

- `unsigned char`
- `unsigned short int`
- `unsigned int`
- `unsigned long int`
- `unsigned long long int`, since C++11.

Each one differs with the other in the range of values it can represent.

Comment: `unsigned char` declares variables that store natural numbers ? Why `char` ? Doesn't `char` declare characters ?

Answer (score 4):

If you need numbers that can't be negative, your best bet would be `unsigned int`. If you want to learn more about data types, you can check [this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Comment: Probably this is what I'm looking for but I have seen to many discussions about `unsigned` vs `unsigned int` and I have some doubts.

Comment: @Skyp89 What "doubts"? `unsigned` and `unsigned int` declare the same thing. The `int` is optional/implied. (Also, `signed`, `signed int`, and bare `int` are all equivalent.) Personally, for semantics, I use `signed` and `unsigned` wherever I specifically care about signage, and `int` if it's irrelevant (which only really happens when calling others' functions).

Answer (score -1):

There's not any particular data type representing natural numbers. But you can use data types for whole numbers and then make some appropriate edits. Here are a few ways to declare whole numbers:

```
 - unsigned short int

 - unsigned int

 - unsigned long int

 - unsigned long long int
```